# Add comments before each line when exporting array with numpy.savetxt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, export

I would like to export an array adding comments at the start of each line and of each column.

For instance with the following array :

```
[[10,5,2],
 [7,2,6],
 [8,3,1]]
```

I would like the output file to look like this (or similar):

```
    1C  2C  3C
1L  10;  5;  2
2L   7;  2;  6
3L   8;  3;  1
```

The issue is that numpy arrays don't accept different types (integers and strings mixed in an array), so I can't export simply with np.savetxt.

Comment: `savetxt` is a rather simply Python function that iterates through the rows of the array, formats them (using your `fmt`) and does a file write.  Write your own if `savetxt` doesn't give you the right format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this directly in `numpy`, but you could always iterate through the array and write your comments and the line to a file.

```
a = np.array([[10,5,2],[7,2,6],[8,3,1]])

print("   " + " ".join([str(x+1)+"C" for x in range(a.shape[1])]))
for i, row in enumerate(a):
    print("%dL %s" % (i+1, "; ".join(map(str, row))))
#   1C 2C 3C
#1L 10; 5; 2
#2L 7; 2; 6
#3L 8; 3; 1
```

To write to a file:

```
with(open('path/to/file', 'w') as f):
    header = "   " + " ".join([str(x+1)+"C" for x in range(a.shape[1])])
    f.write(header + "\n")
    for i, row in enumerate(a):
        line = "%dL %s" % (i+1, "; ".join(map(str, row)))
        f.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: `savetxt` does (more or less) `f.write(fmt%tuple(row))`.